# Why do I sometimes get an attachment id string instead of a url from an image's guid field in the post table?

Tags: media-library

If I do a query of the post table for post type 'attachment' sometimes the guid field will contain an attachment id, "http://sitename.com/?attachment_id=1201", instead of a URL. How can I convert a string like this into the attachment url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that part of the actual path, relative to the uploads folder, is stored in the postmeta table for the meta_key of '_wp_attached_file' which can be obtained, as Milo suggested, by using wp_get_attachment_url.

Comment: This is kind of just a coincidence. So NEVER use this to get a URL, there are countless situations this will fail badly.

Comment: Agreed. From now on I will use the path from the postmeta table.

Answer (score 1):

GUIDs aren't URLs, they are unique identifiers for feed readers. The GUID should never be used in any other way.

See [`wp_get_attachment_url`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) and [`get_attachment_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attachment_link).